# Weird error when I create a blendshape

Tags: error

I am creating a blendshape of a model that gets smaller and this happens with his hands when I shrink it:

[image]
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is your armature in rest (bind) pose? It looks like there is and armature deformation after the shapekey. Try hiding your armature modifier and check if the problem is still there.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that there is a relative deformation applied to the mesh after the shapekey.

This is likely to be caused by a deforming modifier, like an armature modifier. Modifiers are applied after shapekeys. To properly view your shapekey in object mode you can

- turn of (the armature) modifier
- reset the armature to rest pose with the **Rest Position** button
  [image: res position]
  The armature will be unposable as long as this button is activated.
- reset the transformations of the armature, by

  1. showing all armature layers
  2. selecting all bones in pose mode (<kbd>A</kbd>)
  3. Removing keyframes which would prevent the bones from being reset.
  4. clearing their transformations with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Translation), <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (Rotation) and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (scale).